# Inject SessionExtensions Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the below class named SessionExtensions to set and get complex object (User Class)

```
public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to inject it into a view to display the first and last name of a user but all examples are using `Session.GetString` instead of `Get<User>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't inject a static class. It's just available. That's what `static` means. In particular, extensions will just naturally appear on the types they extend, as long as they're in an available namespace. That last part is probably your issue. For example, if your extension class is in `Namspace.To.My.Extensions`, then, in your view (or in `_ViewImports.cshtml`, you need to add `@using Namespace.To.My.Extensions`.

You 100% do not need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`. A view has built-in access to `HttpContext` already, since it's part of the request pipeline. Session, in particular, is available directly, as well. So all you need is:

```
@Session.Get<User>("user_login_credentionals").FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to my questions:

First I have to include and inject the following into my view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@using MenaProjects.Util
@using MenaProjects.Models
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
```

Then i my html code to access my complex object:

```
@(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<User>("user_login_credentionals").FirstName)
```